# weird URL - using cloud to create a redirect link

Tags: html, email, redirect, hyperlink

once i was checking my mail, and one of the suspicious mail included many links that all look the pretty much the same,

***Link-1 =>*** `https:// nxavcsqxn.blob.core.windows.net/omdnicmtm/e3a9rw.html#qs=op-aekfgahdhbeiikfaefejbehaejcfcjkaehjkeabaehjkeabackahcaccafgfacgicagbjgbacb`

***Link-2 =>*** `https:// nxavcsqxn.blob.core.windows.net/omdnicmtm/e3a9rw.html#qs=ua-aekfgahdhbeiikfaefejbehaejcfcjkaehjkeabaehjkeabackahcaccafgfacgicagbjgbacb`

the two links looks the same but it redirect to two deferent urls

*"...#qs=**ua**-..."*
*"...#qs=**op**-..."*

i have been studying this two links for a while, but didn't came to a good conclusion
*any ideas on how did the original editor created this kind of urls*.

[Check this](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#microsoft-azure-blob-storage)
this may help

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Gcr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the source code of the HTML page, it only has one line of JavaScript:

```
document.location.href = 'http://example.com/'+window.location.href.split('#')[1];
```

So when the page loads, the script **checks the URL** for what's after the `#`, and redirects to another, redirecter domain. The two cases end up being:

```
http://example.com/op-aekfgahdhbeiikfaefejbehaejcfcjkaehjkeabaehjkeabackahcaccafgfacgicagbjgbacb
http://example.com/ua-aekfgahdhbeiikfaefejbehaejcfcjkaehjkeabaehjkeabackahcaccafgfacgicagbjgbacb
```

which become different URLs.

Comment: can you explain more plz,

Comment: what HTML page did you check it source and how ?

Comment: I downloaded the page using `wget`.

Comment: whole morning i just understood the first part of you answer,

Comment: any idea on how to create the second part of the answer - create what came after # -